# FirebaseDB GetValue gets data if there is no connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

Using **App Inventor** I created a timer, which checks the connection every 3 seconds. It sets the text of a label to "No connection" and immediately replaces it with "connected to computer" or "computer not connected" if there is a connection.

I thought if there is no connection, the text of the label would not be replaced so it would show "No connection" but it is replaced with "computer not connected" although it can not get any value from firebase. So what do I fail to see? Does the `FirebaseDB` not work like I think it does?

My Code:

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: let's see, if MIT will have an answer about that issue here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/whGw7wQejOg/-OdPBBMmBQAJ